# Quartz.Net -How to Persist Last RunTime on Service restarts

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, quartz.net

I am running a service using Quartz.Net version 2.0 .I want to keep last run time programatically.Currently i am trying to use JobDataMap for this.This will fail if any service restart happens.How i will keep lastruntime even on service restarts.

```
 [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
class Job1 : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        string lastrun =   (string)context.MergedJobDataMap["LastRunDate"];

        context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put("LastRunDate", DateTime.Now.ToString());  
    }
}
```

In Job.xml i am configuring like

```
       <job-data-map>
    <entry>
      <key>LastRunDate</key>
      <value></value>
    </entry>
  </job-data-map>
```

So question is whether Quartz JobDataMap persist job properties across restarts?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a `AdoJobStore` for [that](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html).

It supports these providers:

- SqlServer-20 - SQL Server driver for .NET Framework 2.0
- OracleODP-20 - Oracle's Oracle Driver
- OracleODPManaged-1123-40 Oracle's managed driver for Oracle 11
- OracleODPManaged-1211-40 Oracle's managed driver for Oracle 12
- MySql-50 - MySQL Connector/.NET v. 5.0 (.NET 2.0)
- MySql-51 - MySQL Connector/:NET v. 5.1 (.NET 2.0)
- MySql-65 - MySQL Connector/:NET v. 6.5 (.NET 2.0)
- SQLite-10 - SQLite ADO.NET 2.0 Provider v. 1.0.56 (.NET 2.0)
- Firebird-201 - Firebird ADO.NET 2.0 Provider v. 2.0.1 (.NET 2.0)
- Firebird-210 - Firebird ADO.NET 2.0 Provider v. 2.1.0 (.NET 2.0)
- Npgsql-20 - PostgreSQL Npgsql

and if you want to read something about the implementation you can find lot of useful information in this blog: [part1](http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/configuring-quartznet-with-adonet-job.html) and [part2](http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/configuring-quartznet-with-adonet-job_28.html).